# Replace non-printing character in csv with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch file that imports a csv file into an SQL database, but the source data often contains non-printing characters (Excel code(10)) which cause problems during import.

How can I remove the char(10)'s as part of the batch file?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by code(10) and char(10)'s. For instance SQL error code 10 is usually 'Service not Running', however characters could mean, octal character 010, (backspace), decimal character 10, (line feed), or hexadecimal character 0x10, (data link escape).

Comment: In Excel, char(10) or code(10) is a new line character. The csv I am importing has cells with new lines in it, which I need to remove. As I have a batch file which I am using to import the data into MSSQL, I am looking for a way to remove these new line characters as one of the first steps in the batch file

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you saying that you have some records in your CSV, which include multiline fields. Also just to clarify, from my previous comment, you appear to be trying to remove decimal character `10`, which are line feeds.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `powershell.exe`, PowerShell's [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) from your batch file as follows:

```
powershell -c "(Get-Content -Raw in.csv) -replace '(?<!\r)\n', ' ' | Set-Content out.csv"
```

The above:

- reads file `in.csv` in full
- replaces all stand-alone LF (LINE FEED, [`U+000A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a)) characters (i.e., ones that aren't part of a CRLF Windows-style newline) with a space character
- saves the output to `out.csv` (you could save back to the same file, though there is a hypothetical risk of data loss, if the process of saving back is interrupted)

You may have to use [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)'s `-Encoding` parameters to control input and output encoding.